# Add camel route at runtime using end points configured in property file

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I own a spring application and want to add camel routes dynamically  during my application startup.End points are configured in property file and are loaded at run time.
Using Java DSL, i am using for loop to create all routes,

```
for(int i=0;i<allEndPoints;i++)
  {
  DynamcRouteBuilder route = new 
   DynamcRouteBuilder(context,fromUri,toUri) 
camelContext.addRoutes(route)

}
private class DynamcRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    private final String from;
    private final String to;

    private MyDynamcRouteBuilder(CamelContext context, String from, String to) {
        super(context);
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(from).to(to);
    }
}
```

but getting below exception while creating first route itself

Failed to create route file_routedirect: at: >>> OnException[[class org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException] -> [Log[Exception trapped ${exception.class}], process[Processor@0x0]]] <<< in route: Route(file_routedirect:)[[From[direct:... because of ref must be specified on: process[Processor@0x0]\n\ta

Not sure about it- what is the issue ? Can someone has any suggestion or fix for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, to create routes in an iteration it is nice to have some *object that holds the different values for one route*. Let's call this `RouteConfiguration`, a simple POJO with String fields for `from`, `to` and `routeId`.

We are using **YAML files** to configure such things because you have a **real List format** instead of using "flat lists" in property files (`route[0].from`, `route[0].to`).

If you use **Spring** you can directly transform such a "list of object configurations" into a Collection of objects using `@ConfigurationProperties`

When you are able to create such a Collection of value objects, you can simply iterate over it. Here is a strongly simplified example.

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    createConfiguredRoutes();
}

void createConfiguredRoutes() {
    configuration.getRoutes().forEach(this::addRouteToContext);
}

// Implement route that is added in an iteration
private void addRouteToContext(final RouteConfiguration routeConfiguration) throws Exception {
    this.camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from(routeConfiguration.getFrom())
                .routeId(routeConfiguration.getRouteId())
                ...
                .to(routeConfiguration.getTo());
        }
    });
}
```